# Incorrectly ordered contents with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, include

I am trying to add some horizontal bars to the contents of my thesis, to split it up a little. However, I am finding that the horizontal bars do not appear where I set them. As an MWE I have written the following document:

```
\documentclass{report}

%Horizontal line in toc
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand\tocrule{\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\tocrule
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

The file chapter1 is simply `\chapter{My chapter 1}` and chapter2 similarly `\include{chapter2}`. When I make the document, the horizontal bar is below chapter 2 in the contents. Something strange is going on with the interaction between `\cftaddtitleline` and `\include`. If the `\chapter`s are in the main document then the contents page renders fine. Obviously, for my thesis, I don't want everything in one file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}` writes `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\rule  {\textwidth }{0.4pt}}{}}` to the main aux file, *when the current page is shipped out*.

`\include` writes *immediatley* an *@input* command for the own aux file of the included tex file to the main aux file. So, if the `\cftaddtitleline` command appears on the same page as `\include` the `\@input` for the special aux goes to the main aux before the `\@writefile{toc}` … .

Therefore the resulting main aux file of your example is:

```
...
\@input{chapter1.aux}
\@input{chapter2.aux}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\rule  {\textwidth }{0.4pt}}{}}
...
```

AFAIK this behaviour of `\include` can not be changed.

But here are at least three possible solutions:

1. You could use `\input` instead `\include`:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
%Horizontal line in toc
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand\tocrule{\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{chapter1}
\tocrule
\input{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

2. Move `\tocrule` in file chapter2.tex:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter2.tex}
\tocrule
\chapter{Bar}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
%Horizontal line in toc
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand\tocrule{\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

3. You could load package `scrlfile` and use `\BeforeFile{chapter2.tex}{\tocrule}` before `\include{chapter2}`:

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
%Horizontal line in toc
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand\tocrule{\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}}

\usepackage{scrlfile}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\BeforeFile{chapter2.tex}{\tocrule}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter1.tex}
\chapter{Foo}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter2.tex}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
%Horizontal line in toc
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand\tocrule{\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}{}}

\usepackage{scrlfile}
\BeforeFile{chapter2.tex}{\tocrule}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I thought it was somthing weird with \include, I'll have a look at what scrlfile has to offer